# How do I make a dynamic image in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have an image in my report. In the image expression, I want to do something like this:

```
if ($F{num} >= 10) {
    "C:\\Users\\zoudi\\workspace\\bfms\\red.jpg"
}
else if ($F{num} > 0) {
    "C:\\Users\\zoudi\\workspace\\bfms\\red.jpg"
}
else {}
```

Obviously, this syntax is not correct. What is the correct way to go about creating a dynamic image like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Groovy, try:

```
 ($F{num} >= 10) ? "C:\\Users\\zoudi\\workspace\\bfms\\red.jpg" : 
     ($F{num} > 0) ? "C:\\Users\\zoudi\\workspace\\bfms\\blue.jpg" :
           "C:\\Users\\zoudi\\workspace\\bfms\\yellow.jpg"
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much! Thanks for all your help fellow Baltimorean!

Comment: If you can, click the check mark to denote that you accept my answer as your preferred solution. Thanks!